# Calling a function inside click handler, not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

## Problem

I'm calling the function `resetSelection` that should remove `.is-active` classes and add a class of `is-inactive` to a list of hockey players, amongst other things, after the submit button `.btn--submit` has been clicked.

Right now, the `.is-active` classes remain on the picked players and the function does not run?

### index.html

```
<button class="btn btn--submit"><img src="src/img/ballot-alt.png" class="image--ballot">Submit Vote</button>
```

### scripts.js

```
function resetSelection() {
    $(".btn--reset").on("click", function(){
        $(".picked").removeClass("is-active");
        $(".picked").addClass("is-inactive");
        $(".icon-checkmark").removeClass("is-completed");
        $(".btn--submit").hide();
        $(".btn--submit").removeClass("slideLeft");
        starredGoaltenders = 0;
        starredDefencemen = 0;
        starredForwards = 0;
        console.log(starredGoaltenders, starredDefencemen, starredForwards);
    });
} resetSelection();

$(".btn--submit").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
    resetSelection();
});
```

Comment: Logic!! You don't need two classes `is-active` and `is-inactive`, simply use the inactive styles right inside your CSS's `.picked` class.

Comment: Also could you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: Also notice that `resetSelection()` will just assign a new click handler to your `.btn-reset` elements, without immediately triggering anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function binds a click handler event to elements with the class `btn--reset`.  Consider refactoring `resetSelection` to include the logic within that event handler, but not the event handler itself:

```
function resetSelection() {
    $(".picked").removeClass("is-active");
    $(".picked").addClass("is-inactive");
    $(".icon-checkmark").removeClass("is-completed");
    $(".btn--submit").hide();
    $(".btn--submit").removeClass("slideLeft");
    starredGoaltenders = 0;
    starredDefencemen = 0;
    starredForwards = 0;
    console.log(starredGoaltenders, starredDefencemen, starredForwards);
}

$(".btn--reset").on("click", resetSelection);

$(".btn--submit").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
    resetSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `reselectSelection()` function contains an click event handler for `.btn--reset`. Remove that handler and it should work for you because you want to trigger reset function when `.btn--submit` is clicked.